# CTI integration for dynamics crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to do CTI ( computer telephony integration ) for Dynamics CRM 2013. Where I want to create UI like field explore ( left aligned) common to all entities.
I have created web resource to create my UI. But now able to find place holder just like Field explorer.
I added my web resource to form/dashboard but that is particular to that dashboard. Where I want to have such UI component which will receive callback event from CTI respective of which forms currently loaded in CRM.

Any views on this, if I get at least a pointer would be a great help.

For salesforce they have CTI developer GUI, where they have given place holder for CTI UI, I am looking for such place holder for Dynamics CRM 2013 or CTI developer guide (tried may a times,got client extension help on msdn but that did not help).

Comment: https://crmcca.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS has developed USD for call centers (replaces CCA).  It has a CTI "mini" panel on top by default.  You can create global panels or session panel.  You can even create a custom layout.  [Unified Service Desk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43110)